# Check distance of Marker from Polyline

Tags: android, google-maps, sdk, google-polyline

I have a list of markers, and I'm trying to find if any of them are on a polyline that I have created. If not exactly on the polyline, maybe on a close distance. I found many ways to do that in javascript, but it seems the Android API doesn't have any.